# mpi matrix multiplication to run with a different number of processors

Tags: c, arrays, algorithm, mpi, matrix-multiplication

So I got the code working for when running on 1 process. Although when I try to run it on more then 2 processers or more(mpirun -n 4)(mpirun -n 8)etc; half my results are coming back as zero.Im assuming because it doesn't deal with the case where the number of processors is divisible by the matrix size. Any ideas? I'm trying to initialize both matrixes from command line and perform matrix multiplication using MPI. I'm knew to this and would love any help. For example when I enter in a size of 2 and initialize matrix A to the values {1,4,6,7} and matrix B to {8,9,4,5} my result comes out to be {8,9,0,0}..

```
void init_Matrix(int n, int matrix[n][n])
{

  for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
  {
    for(int j = 0; j < n; j++)
    {
      scanf("%i", &matrix[i][j]);
    }
  }
}


void printMatrix(int n, int matrix[n][n])
{
  for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
  {
    for(int j = 0; j < n; j++)
    {
      printf("%d" , matrix[i][j]);
      printf(" ");
    }
    printf("\n");
  }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
  int rank, size;
  MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &size); //num p
  MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);
  int n;
  if(rank == 0)
  {

    printf("Enter in size of matrix! \x0A");
    scanf("%i",&n);
  }

  MPI_Bcast(&n,1,MPI_INT,0,MPI_COMM_WORLD);
  int A[n][n];
  int B[n][n];
  int C[n][n];
  int aa[n/size][n];
  int cc[n/size][n];
if(rank == 0)
{
    init_Matrix(n,A);
    init_Matrix(n,B);
}
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
  for(int j = 0; j < n; j++)
  {
    cc[i][j] = 0;
  }
}
  //scatter rows of first matrix to different processes
  MPI_Scatter(A, n*n/size, MPI_INT, aa, n*n/size, MPI_INT,0,MPI_COMM_WORLD);
  //broadcast second matrix to all processes
  MPI_Bcast(B, n*n, MPI_INT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

  MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);
  //perform vector multiplication by all processes
    for(int k = 0; k < n/size; k++)
    {
      for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
      {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
        {
          cc[i][j] += A[i][k] * B[k][j];
        }
      }
    }

  MPI_Gather(cc, n*n/size, MPI_INT, C, n*n/size, MPI_INT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
  MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);
  if(rank == 0){
    printMatrix(n, C);
  }
  MPI_Finalize();
}
```

updated:
updated attempt using mpi scatterv and mpi gather

:

```
void initMatrix(int Size, int matrix[Size][Size])

{



  for(int i = 0; i < Size; i++)

  {

    for(int j = 0; j < Size; j++)

      scanf("%i", &matrix[i][j]);

  }

}



void multIJK(int Size, int A[Size][Size], int B[Size][Size], int pResult[Size])

{

  for(int i = 0; i < Size; i++)

  {

    for(int j = 0; j < Size; j++)

    {

      for(int k = 0; k < Size; k++)

        pResult += A[i][k] * B[k][j];

    }

  }

}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

  int Size;

  int RowNum;

  int ProcNum;

  int ProcRank;

  MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);

  MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &ProcNum);

  MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &ProcRank);



  if (ProcRank == 0) {     

    printf("Enter in size of matrix! \x0A"); 

    scanf("%i", &Size);

  }   

  int aMatrix[Size][Size];

  int bMatrix[Size][Size];





  MPI_Bcast(&Size, 1, MPI_INT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

  int RestRows = Size;  

  for (int i=0; i<ProcRank; i++)      

    RestRows = RestRows-RestRows/(ProcNum-i);   

  RowNum = RestRows/(ProcNum-ProcRank);

  int pResult[Size];   

  int pProcRows[RowNum*Size];   

  int pProcResult[RowNum];

  if(ProcRank == 0) 

  {

      initMatrix(Size,aMatrix);

      initMatrix(Size,bMatrix);

  } 



  RestRows=Size; // Number of rows, that haven’t been distributed yet

  MPI_Bcast(bMatrix, Size, MPI_DOUBLE, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);



  // Alloc memory for temporary objects  

  // the number of elements sent to the process   

  int pSendInd[ProcNum];  

 // the index of the first data element sent to the process   

 int pSendNum[ProcNum];



  // Define the disposition of the matrix rows for current process   

  RowNum = (Size/ProcNum);   

  pSendNum[0] = RowNum*Size;  

  pSendInd[0] = 0;   

  for (int i=1; i<ProcNum; i++) {    

    RestRows -= RowNum;     

    RowNum = RestRows/(ProcNum-i);     

    pSendNum[i] = RowNum*Size;    

    pSendInd[i] = pSendInd[i-1]+pSendNum[i-1]; 

  }



  // Scatter the rows  

  MPI_Scatterv(aMatrix , pSendNum, pSendInd, MPI_INT, pProcRows, 

      pSendNum[ProcRank], MPI_DOUBLE, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);



  multIJK(Size,aMatrix,bMatrix,pResult);



  RestRows=Size; // Number of rows, that haven’t been distributed yet



  //Alloc memory for temporary objects  

  // Number of elements, that current process sends  

  int pReceiveNum[ProcNum];   



  /* Index of the first element from current process in result vector */   

  int pReceiveInd[ProcNum];



  //Define the disposition of the result vector block of current processor  

  pReceiveInd[0] = 0;  

  pReceiveNum[0] = Size/ProcNum;  

  for (int i=1; i<ProcNum; i++) {  

    RestRows -= pReceiveNum[i-1];    

    pReceiveNum[i] = RestRows/(ProcNum-i);    

    pReceiveInd[i] = pReceiveInd[i-1]+pReceiveNum[i-1];  

  }   //Gather the whole result vector on every processor  

  MPI_Allgatherv(pProcResult, pReceiveNum[ProcRank], MPI_INT, pResult, 

      pReceiveNum, pReceiveInd, MPI_DOUBLE, MPI_COMM_WORLD);





  //ProcessTermination(aMatrix,bMatrix, pResult, pProcRows, pProcResult);

  if(ProcRank == 0)

  {

    for(int i = 0; i < Size; i++)

    {

      printf("%i\n",pResult[i]);

    }



  }

  MPI_Finalize();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have some logic problems.

```
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) <-- this should be until n/size, you are going into unallocated memory
{
   for(int j = 0; j < n; j++)
   {
     cc[i][j] = 0;
   }
}
```

```
cc[i][j] += A[i][k] * B[k][j]; <-- again, going outsize allocated memory
```

Replace it with

```
cc[k][i] += A[k][j] * B[j][i];
```

Hopefully these are all the problems.
You should also treat the cases where the matrix size is not divisible by the number of processors.

Comment: how do I traded such cases? So if(n%size !=0) {what should I be doing?} sorry im new and not sure what to do with remaining rows in matrix @Mirea Radu

Comment: You need to send to the first ```r``` processors (where ```r``` is the remainder ```of n/size```) one more row. Unfortunately you will need to use other methods than ```MPI_Bcast``` and ```MPI_Scatter``` for that.

Comment: so im assuming instead of MPI_Bcast for matrix B and MPI_Scatter for matrix A I should be using MPI_Scatterv for both?

Comment: Considering that the volume of data that you send and receive is different between processors, I was thinking about ```MPI_Send``` and ```MPI_Recv``` used in a loop.

Comment: you have more rows than MPI tasks, and this is not supported by your code. the canonical way of dealing with this is to use `MPI_Scatterv()` and `MPI_Gatherv()`

Comment: so I've tried using MPI_scatterv and MPI_Gatherv and I keep getting bus errors and wrong data. Sorry I really knew to this if you could take a look at the updated code that'd be appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: I do not see gatherv nor scatterv in the posted code.

Comment: seems to be in the answer section or something for some reason. But I do use scatterv and allgatherv